# How to prove that Navier-Stokes equations are Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, lorentz-symmetry, navier-stokes

I've been hearing recently that the Navier-Stokes (NS) equations are invariant under a Lorentz transformation, so I tried to prove it just changing terms of transformed velocity instead of the velocity,

$$u(\vec r,t)_{i}=\frac{u'(\vec r,t)_{i}+v}{1+\frac{v}{c}u'(\vec r,t)_{i}}$$

in

$$\rho[\partial_{t}u(\vec r,t)_{i}+u(\vec r,t)_{j}\partial^{j}u(\vec r,t)_{i}]=\eta\partial^{j}\partial^{j}u(\vec r,t)_{i}-\partial^{i}P+\rho\vec f$$

but suddenly I noted that in the NS equations the velocity depends on space and time $v(\vec r,t)$ and in special relativity does not depends on, I guess.

Now I feel a little bit confused about. Do I have to find a new Lorentz transformation for the velocity $v(\vec r,t)$? Do I need to introduce information about the metric tensor? is there another way to prove it? What about the pressure and the force terms?

I just want a way to proceed, I don't really want all the answers. Thanks for the read. I'm an undergraduate.

Comment: Where did you read that NS is Lorentz invariant?

Comment: I had heard from college friends, then i decide to try to prove it . is it incorrect?

Comment: No, but there is a relativistic generalization of the NS equation.

Comment: @RicardoGuzman I think it's great that you, as an undergrad, are trying to learn physics beyond the syllabus. I want to encourage you in the future to *always* cite your sources: every claim you make has to be come hand in hand a link to a reputable source where you read it. If you heard it from someone else, ask them for a source. Making claims without a source is inadmissible in science. It takes some time to learn that, but you'll have to sooner or later. Good luck!

Comment: You're right. Sorry for my bad english (i'm spanish speaker).

Comment: As already noticed, Navier-Stokes equations are NOT Lorentz invariant. See this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730551/226902